# Issues with jQuery/CSS Nav not hiding and horizontal position

Tags: jquery, css

UPDATE: Horizontal positioning has been resolved, but still having issues with menus not disappearing.

Updated JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/trevoray/CrPdK/7/

I've come across two issues with my nav that I can't get past. Can anyone take a look and help me out?

1. Horizontal position. The page is centered, so I don't know exact position. I made it absolute and thought it would be absolute based upon it's parent element, but it's not working. I need the horizontal position to always be the same regardless of how wide a user's browser is.
2. Menus not "hiding" after onmouseout. Can't seem to figure out how to get the menus to go away consistantly.

Here's the jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/trevoray/CrPdK/2/

```
 #nav-about { z-index:4000; position:absolute; left:186px;  display:none;}
 #nav-meetings { z-index:4000; position:absolute; left:357px; display:none;}
 #nav-journal { z-index:4000; position:absolute; left:528px;  display:none;}
 #nav-goodstuff { z-index:4000; position:absolute; left:699px; display:none;}
 #nav-members { z-index:4000; position:absolute; left:819px; display:none;}
```

[image]

Comment: didn't understood your first requirement properly. could you be a bit more precise?

Comment: @I_Debug_Everything I want the vertical edge of the menu to be aligned with the vertical edge of the nav buttons. And not have it's position changed if the browser is widened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To position an element absolute relative to its parent. The parent element needs `position: relative`

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="absolute">
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.parent { position: relative; }
.absolute { position: absolute; top: 10px; right; 20px }
```

2. You've put the `onmouseout` handler onto the submenus. So if you leave the menu point with the mouse, nothing happens, if you leave the submenu, the submenu will hide.

## Update

I have created a working example now: http://jsfiddle.net/VZ7qD/1

Things to note:

1. You actually don't need the JavaScript. See the commented out last CSS statement. This is enough, however with the CSS there is no animation when showing. (I personally find `slideDown`/`slideUp` nicer than the default animation of `show` btw.)
2. The JavaScript is binding the `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` handlers to the top navigation `li` element that holds the submenu. The submenu is a child of this `li` item.
3. I applied your background color and gradient by applying one single gray gradient for all elements and then only add a border of the desired color to the link element instead of adding a gradient area that is actually one plain color.
4. Use your IDs for defining custom background colors for the links in all submenus (similar to the fat bottom border on the top menu items)

Comment: Thanks @ohcibi!! That worked for the horizontal positioning. Now I'm still having issues with nav menus not disappaering. So you're saying I'm not supposed to use onmouseout?

UPDATED CODE:

http://jsfiddle.net/trevoray/CrPdK/7/

Comment: wow, awesome! i didn't think this design was possible using LI, which was my preferred method. thanks!

Comment: hi @ohcibi, I'm having an issue w/ your updated code on the rest of my site. I had to update it so that the styles wouldn't affect every <UL> on my site, but now the bullet points for the list items are displaying. Can you take a look at my updated code and tell me what I did wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/trevoray/VZ7qD/10/

Comment: By prepending `#navMenu` to the style that disables the bullet points you've disabled this style for the `#navMenu` itself, because it only applys to its children now. So just add a `, #navMenu` to your updated selectors or put everything into a wrapper `<div>` or better `<nav>`. http://jsfiddle.net/ohcibi/VZ7qD/14/.

Comment: oh i didn't know about that feature! doing it now, also, any ideas on how to make second row of text indented? the padding in  your code seems to prevent this.

Comment: it says voting requires 15 pts reputation which I apparently don't have.

Comment: Maybe you should post a new question. Don't know what you mean and this seems to have nothing to do with your original problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Updated your fiddle:

**Demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/CrPdK/3/

See the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` function for `#Meetings` and `#nav-meetings` and replicate it for all the others.

Didn't understood your first requirement.

Comment: tks, but it's not working. The menus still don't disappear. I'm using Mac Chrome. I've updated original post with screenshot of what I'm talking about. 

Also the first requirement means that I want the horizontal position of each menu to be directly aligned with it's corresponding button. Currently, the horizontal position changes when browser width is changed beyond 1050px.